# Is there a way to have "snapback" in tmux?

Tags: tmux

Can I configure `tmux` so that once I enter scrollback, starting to type a new command (e.g. any letter, but any printable character would also work) will exit scrollback and pass that letter to the session? Like PuTTY's "Reset scrollback on keypress" option or similar options in other terminals.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer. May not be the *best* answer, but it works. The trick is to bind all unmodified keys in the `copy-mode` table to 1) cancel copy mode and 2) send themselves to the session. So in `tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode a send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys a
bind-key -T copy-mode b send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys b
bind-key -T copy-mode c send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys c
bind-key -T copy-mode d send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys d
bind-key -T copy-mode e send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys e
bind-key -T copy-mode f send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys f
bind-key -T copy-mode g send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys g
bind-key -T copy-mode h send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys h
bind-key -T copy-mode i send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys i
bind-key -T copy-mode j send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys j
bind-key -T copy-mode k send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys k
bind-key -T copy-mode l send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys l
bind-key -T copy-mode m send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys m
bind-key -T copy-mode n send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys n
bind-key -T copy-mode o send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys o
bind-key -T copy-mode p send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys p
bind-key -T copy-mode q send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys q
bind-key -T copy-mode r send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys r
bind-key -T copy-mode s send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys s
bind-key -T copy-mode t send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys t
bind-key -T copy-mode u send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys u
bind-key -T copy-mode v send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys v
bind-key -T copy-mode w send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys w
bind-key -T copy-mode x send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys x
bind-key -T copy-mode y send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys y
bind-key -T copy-mode z send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys z
```

And so on and on. You have to map each key individually, including upper/lowercase variations.

Wrote a little Python script (`snapback.py`) to write all those lines:

```
import string

for c in string.printable:
    if ord(c) > 31:     # printable contains control chars we don't want
        c = repr(c).replace(r"\\", "\\").replace(r";", r"\;")
        print('bind-key -T copy-mode', c,
              'send-keys -X cancel \; send-keys', c.replace(";", r"\;"))
```

Usage:

```
python snapback.py >> ~/.tmux.conf
```

Comment: It is too bad that you can't use a for loop for this.

Comment: I did end up writing a short Python script that generated most of this for me. Semicolon needed special handling, though.